# My code isn't handling the exception (python)

Tags: python

I am trying to write a class to display the width of square which will handle the exception of being passed a negative number.

```
class Square:       
    def __init__(self,width):
        try:
            self.width = width
        except ValueError:
            print("Width cannot be less than zero.")

    def __repr__(self):
        return 'Square({0})'.format(self.width)

    def __str__(self):
        return "Square(" + str(self.width) + ")"
```

At the moment this code will give the correct output for positive input, but the exception is not being handled, instead upon input of say, -10, the code gives me `Square(-10)`. I can't seem to see what's wrong.

Comment: you code not only works for positive but also negative.

Comment: When you say `self.width = width`, do you thing that there is something that will cause exception? Here python does n't care whether `width` is negative or not. You have to take care of that.

Answer (score 3):

Your try block doesn't catch an error because there is nothing wrong with assigning a variable a negative value.  You need to check for this yourself and raise the appropriate error.

```
def __init__(self, width):
    if width < 0:
        raise ValueError('Width cannot be less than zero.')
    self.width = width
```

Answer (score 2):

It's because negative `width` is a valid number and assign it to `self.width` does not raise `ValueError`. Instead of handing exception you can do a simple `if` check.

```
def __init__(self, width):
    if width < 0:
        print('Width cannot be less than zero.')
    else:
        self.width = width
```

Answer (score 2):

Python does n't care whether `width` is zero or not. You have to take care of that.
You may rewrite your code in this way.

```
class Square:    

    def __init__(self,width):
        try:
            if width < 0:
                 raise ValueError("Negative value of width")
            self.width = width
        except ValueError:
            print("Width cannot be less than zero.")

    def __repr__(self):
        return 'Square({0})'.format(self.width)

    def __str__(self):
        return "Square(" + str(self.width) + ")"
```

Answer (score 2):

you can use assert for raising error: `assert width>0,'error'`

Answer (score 2):

You can try out this

```
class Square:    
    def __init__(self,width):
        try:
            if width < 0:
                 raise ValueError
            self.width = width
        except ValueError:
            print("Width cannot be less than zero."),
        print "Width is : %d" %width

    def __repr__(self):
        return 'Square({0})'.format(self.width)

    def __str__(self):
        return "Square(" + str(self.width) + ")"

obj = Square(10)  # pass positive value
obj = Square(-10) # pass negative value
```

Answer (score 2):

What about this:

```
    self.width = width
    if self.width < 0:
        raise ValueError('Width cannot be less than zero.')
```